# Time Capsule and multiple Macs

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

Does the Time Capule support Time Machine backups from multiple macs out of the box?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. Each Mac get's it's own sparse bundle disk image.

Comment: /me acting dumb. What's a sparse bundle disk image?

Comment: @StuWilson It's an **automatically expanding** disk image which is stored and updated in little **"fragments"**. That way only updated fragments have to be backed up and not the whole image. Because it's automatically expanding, the image takes up only little space when created - it expands as files are added.

Comment: @gentmatt - If "a little space" is ~20 GB, then you are correct. The initial backup will be the size of a complete install of OS X.

Comment: If you create your own new sparse bundle disk image using Disk Utility, you will see that it's not that big. E.g. I've created a 1 TB sparse bundle with an initial size of less than 1GB. That's less than 0.1% of the maximum size which the bundle can hold.

Answer (score 4):

And to support gentmatt's answer, here is [the official documentation of Apple](http://www.apple.com/timecapsule/backup.html):

[image]